# Atomic Increment and Decrement operations with Redis

Tags: c#, .net-core, redis, rabbitmq, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to implement an atomic distributed counter using `Redis`. My usecase is like this:

1. There is a publishing application which publishes messages to `RabbitMQ`. There can be multiple instances of the publisher running, hence they can publish in parallel. These publishers do not know in advance how many messages they are going to publish.
2. There is a consuming applications which subscribes to these messages from `RabbitMQ`. There can be multiple instances of consumer running which can consume in parallel.

My problem is, once the **last** message is consumed by consumer application I want to take certain action (such as publishing one more message).

The solution I cameup with is to implement a sort of distributed reference counting using `Redis`. The idea is that publisher will increment the count in `Redis` as soon as it publishes the message and consumer will decrement the count in `Redis` as soon as it finishes processing. After decrement if the count is `0` that means it is the last message.

However, when I tried to implement a sample application to test this out, I see the increments are not working as expected. This is my sample code:

```
            const string key = "MyKey";
            ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
            var db = redis.GetDatabase();
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Parallel.For(0, 1000, async (_) =>
            {
                    var transaction = db.CreateTransaction();
                    var v = transaction.StringIncrementAsync(key + "-Count").ConfigureAwait(false);
                    await transaction.ExecuteAsync();
                    await v;
            });
```

I expected the value in the `Redis` to be "1000" after the completion. However, it has value such as "nil" or "4". Am I missing something? Is it possible to do this with `Redis`? Note that correct value of the counter is important to me and cannot miss increment/decrement operations. I am using StackExchange Redis library as client.

**EDIT**

I could get it working by changing body of loop to
`db.ScriptEvaluate(@"redis.call('incr', KEYS[1])", new RedisKey[] {key});`.
Can anyone comment whether this is guaranteed to work or its working purely by luck?

Comment: That approach isn't going to work. E.g., if a fast consumer takes the first message quickly, the resulting count is `0` before any of the publishers complete. There's also reliability problems since the publish-message and increment-counter are not atomic. You really need to have some way for the publisher(s) to detect when they complete and add something to the message itself or publish a "done" message.